# Ubuntu Chromium-browser segmentation fault

Tags: ubuntu, chrome, segmentation-fault

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 in [Userland](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tech.ula) android application, on Android 10 and have installed chromium-browser through command line `sudo apt install chromium-browser`.
But when starting it through `chromium-browser`, it only outputs `Segmentation Fault` and nothing else.
What is the issue with this?
How to fix this issue?
Thanks

Comment: That link, unexpectedly, points to another question.

Comment: Sorry , link edited.